# How to list docbroaker configured with the docbase?

Tags: documentum, documentum-dql

Via Documentum Administrator, how is it possible to list the docbroaker configured with the actual accessed docbase?

Comment: The downvotes derive, almost for sure, from someone that doesn't know what Documentum is at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the DQL tools, execute the following command:

```
EXECUTE list_targets;
```